# PyGame Orange boxes only on a Pi

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi2

I have worked on building a GUI for a project. I did this on a Virtual Machine on Ubuntu and everything was working great.

The project is running on a Raspberry Pi 2, so I tried it on my own at home and checked via VNC to see if it all was OK and yes it was.

However, when I ran it on the actual Pi 2 that was going to be in the project I found that there were orange/yellow boxes obscuring my dials. When I brought it home and plugged my Pi into a screen, they were there again.

I am using Python 2.7.9. The Pi is fully up to date. PyGame v1.9 being used.

My Github with the code is here: https://github.com/maza256/PyGame_Dials

Here the difference on the VM and on the Pi:

**On Ubuntu VM**

[image: Ubuntu VM screenshot]

**On Raspberry Pi 2**

[image: On Raspberry Pi 2]

Does anyone know why this is occuring, or a possible solution?

Comment: Questions should be self-containing, so at least insert the images into your post. That said  (I didn't check your code), are those PNG images? Then it's not an "orange box", but rather a problem in your PNG library where its transparency code is malfunctioning. The orange is what's 'really' underneath the transparent pixels.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to embed images.
But a transparency issue maybe the problem. What is a possible solution? Change from PNG to JPG/BMP?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. By replacing the hex values that were used for colour with RGB values instead (so wherever there was a 0xFFFF00, replace it with (255, 255, 0) and it now all works.

I'd love to know why that is, but I have no idea what to search for. If anyone can offer a reason that'd be great.

But solved now.

Comment: What's really odd, `0xFFFF00` is usually the hex representation of `(255,255,0)`. However, it could be the mere act of rewriting your images somehow tugged something loose that got stuck inside the files.